# Visual Studio MVC Oddity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I've been stuck on the same DropDownList problem for days now while working on a MVC project in VS2010. The problem has become even more frustrating right now because when I copy all relevant code into a completely new, blank project, the second instance actually runs perfectly and produces exactly the result I expect...

Controller:

```
<HandleError()> _
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Index() As ActionResult
        ViewData("Message") = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!"

        Return View()
    End Function

    Function About() As ActionResult

        Dim configList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        configList.Add("10GBaseLX4")
        configList.Add("10GFC")
        configList.Add("10GigE")
        configList.Add("100BaseFX")
        configList.Add("Test")

        ViewData("cprotocols") = New SelectList(configList)
        Return View()

    End Function
End Class
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="aboutTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    About Us
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>About</h2>
   <p>
        <% Using Html.BeginForm()%>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("cprotocols") %>
        <% End Using %>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

The page doesn't do anything right now other than simply display a dropdownlist with the options shown hard-coded in the controller, but I'm not even going to bother with writing logic when my current site refuses to even show the list to the user.

The error message is `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'cprotocols'.` but once again, there are no runtime errors when i copy this bit of code over to a blanked solution.

Any ideas how to solve this or even any clues on what is causing such an inconsistency? I don't want to copy over all the other files from my current project into the new one just to have the problem manifest itself again somewhere down the line (which is bound to happen when the code is only half broken...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the module; the code itself is fine. I had to delete Temporary ASP.NET files, clean up my GAC, as well as nuke all current assembly references in my project, clean solution, re-add required references, and finally clean and rebuild. I'm still not clear on why exactly VS2010 was referring to assemblies from an old build (simply cleaning and rebuilding is not enough). I also don't know at what point the environment stops "refreshing" and decides to simply refer to obsolete builds. I'll try to do a bit more research on this point and then add on to this post.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the ViewData key name and see if that helps anywhere. If not, if you can you could create a new project and copy all your existing model/controller/view classes over the other project, this seems like something in your project configuration that could have gone off.

Hope this helps a little :)

Comment: To be honest, when I replace all instances of `cprotocols` in my first project with `protocols`, the page "works" in the sense that it runs. What happened was that the very first time I coded this page, I named the ViewData key `protocols` and only had 2 options (10GBaseLX4 and 100BaseFX) for simplicity. Now, despite my controller adding 3 new selections, the list still only shows the original two. At one point, I had logic behind the DDL (ajax) which was functional at first, but when I changed the message posted back upon selection, the page would display an old message instead.

Comment: That is very strange, perhaps you have some strange caching going on, try to run a **Clean Solution** then **Build Solution** from the Build menu in VS

Comment: Same thing happens. What's even funnier is that I've tried just about every change I can think of on my new project (changing the ViewData variable name, adding options, deleting options, changing messages, reattempting in a new browser, etc.) and everything works as it should even with the Ajax caching that supposedly occurs under the hood and has been known to occasionally break some scripts. I guess I'll just copy all my old code over then. Thanks!

Comment: Unbelievable... the new site now exhibits the same behavior as the old one. I might just abandon Html Helpers for good.

Comment: Perhaps there's an issue with the development server and/or VS. Have you tried to deploy the website to IIS? You could also try to repair VS through the control panel.

Comment: Yes, I've deployed the site to IIS and testing the page there gives me a runtime error as well. I'll try to take a look at VS through the control panel then.